# How do I count the rows with a where clause in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am pretty much stuck with a problem I am facing with SQL Server. I want to show in a query the amount of times that specific value occurs. This is pretty easy to do, but I want to take it a step further and I think the best way to explain on what I am trying to achieve is to explain it using images.

I have two tables:
[Plant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Rbe.png) and
[Chest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEb7n.png)

As you can see with the chest the column 'hoeveelheid' tells how full the chest is, 'vol' == 1 and 3/4 is == 0,75. In the plant table there is a column 'Hoeveelheidperkist' which tells how much plants there can be in 1 chest.

```
select DISTINCT kist.Plantnaam, kist.Plantmaat, count(*) AS 'Amount'
from kist

group by kist.plantnaam, kist.Plantmaat
```

This query counts all the chests, but it does not seperate the count of 'Vol' chests and '3/4' chests. It only does [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzOWV.png). [What I want to achieve is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNL4v.png). But I have no idea how. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use group by you don't need distinct
and if you want the seprated  count for hoeveelheid you ust add to the group  by clause

```
    select DISTINCT kist.Plantnaam, kist.Plantmaat, kist.hoeveelheid, count(*) AS 'Amount'
    from kist
    group by kist.plantnaam, kist.Plantmaat, hoeveelheid
```

or if you want all the 3 count ond the samw rowx  you could use a condition aggreagtion eg:

```
    select DISTINCT kist.Plantnaam, kist.Plantmaat
     , sum(case when kist.hoeveelheid ='Vol' then 1 else  0 end) vol 
     , sum(case when kist.hoeveelheid ='3/3' then 1 else  0 end) 3_4 
     , count(*) AS 'Amount'
    from kist
    group by kist.plantnaam, kist.Plantmaat
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! This definitely helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to filter the data on the counts you have to use **having** clause. When ever you are using aggregate functions(sum, count, min, max) and you want to filter them on aggregation basis, use **having** clause

```
select DISTINCT kist.Plantnaam, kist.Plantmaat, count(*) AS 'Amount'
from kist

group by kist.plantnaam, kist.Plantmaat having count(*) = 1 -- or provide necessary conditions
```